# Выбрать все значения из join таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая задачка, при обычном JOIN между таблицами и применения GROUP BY возвращается одна строка.

Допустим, в таблице `table1` есть 3 строки с `id` равным `table1.id = table2.id`, делая группировку по `table1.id`, я получаю одну строку на выходе.

Как получить на выходе одну строку, в которой бы были все 3 значения из определенного поля таблицы `table1`?
Помнится, что было что-то связанное с CONCUT().

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ', ')](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Comment: Видимо да, спасибо большое, попробую.